# Android - Getting a list of drawable resource

Tags: android

In android you can access a resource with syntax like R..

what I want to do is to reach a set of images has naming convention.

for example I have 4 files in drawable with the names :

draw_1_.jpg

how can I get the list of drawable images to List  ..

This is because, I want to make a slide show.

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, if you know the suffix of the images,  you can request the identifier for a drawable by [getResources().getIdentifier(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and then using the identifier get the drawable. So if you know how many images you have, then you can create a loop and store each of the drawables in a list. Just take into account that such a lookup is relatively expensive.

Comment: this is a good approach but as you said might be expensive for me. I think I will update the code on each upgrade.

Comment: aye, you would want to make such a lookup once, not every draw call, so either store the IDs upon initialization or perhaps the drawables themselves.

Answer (score 7):

I don't believe you can trust the resource compiler to give your images sequential integer values. In the past I've always created a static array to store these.

```
private static int[] imgs = { R.id.draw_1, R.id.draw_2, R.id.draw_3, R.id.draw_4 };
```

With this you can then have a section of code like:

```
int curSlide = 0;
view.setBackgroundResource(imgs[curSlide]);
```

Comment: in above comment ( the one I added to the first answer ) I meant to this approach.

Comment: I decided to use static way of resource access. I think that's enough for my requirement. where I need to show at most 10 images.

Answer (score 4):

Although it is an old question, I just had a similar problem recently. I liked solution of jeffd, but storing a list of images ids in code is not the best idea. So, I created an xml file with the list, which I put in res/xml directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<list>
    <image id="@drawable/draw_1"/>
    <image id="@drawable/draw_2"/>
    <image id="@drawable/draw_3"/>
    <image id="@drawable/draw_4"/>
</list>
```

Images are stored in `drawable` directory and are named `draw_1.jpg`, `draw_2.jpg`, etc.

Using this sort of xml has an advantage that availability of resources is checked at compile time, so if you have a typo, it won't compile.

Retrieving the list in code is simply parsing the xml, yet it's a bit verbose. `XmlPullParser` has method `getAttributeResourceValue` that allows getting resource id without dealing with any strings.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG &&
            parser.getName().equals("image")) {

            int imageId = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < parser.getAttributeCount(); ++i) {
                if (parser.getAttributeName(i).equals("id")) {
                    list.add(parser.getAttributeResourceValue(i, -1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (XmlPullParserException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

Another simpler solution would be using arrays as resources. I haven't tried this out, but you can see an example here: http://www.geeks.gallery/how-to-list-images-from-array-xml-in-android/ This is how to structure your xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="list">
        <item>@drawable/draw_1</item>
        <item>@drawable/draw_2</item>
        <item>@drawable/draw_3</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

To access the array you can use this code:

```
TypedArray list = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.list);
for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); ++i) {
    int id = list.getResourceId(i, -1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should identify all the Image as a Drawable .. and then you can use them as you can !