# How can I connect a string with an image

Tags: android, user-input, android-image

Let me explain my intention. I have lots of images in my drawable resource and there are unique names that are associated to them. I want to get user string input and compare with the one which is viewed by user when the button is clicked. Is there any possibility to add string descriptions to imageview in order to compare with user input? I hope I could explain my intention clearly. And also if two strings are not equal, I want to show feedback and vice versa.

Comment: Well, for instance: _User write a text in a input box, this text must be compared with each name of your drawable resources and then show feedback in each case_ (Exist or not Exist). Use [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and review [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690326/android-getting-a-list-of-drawable-resource).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I really follow your intention but...
If you create a enum which has a description with each you can easily match the description with input.

```
public enum Pic {
 PIC1(R.drawable.example,"This is a description"),
 ....,
 ....;

 private int resource;
 private String description;
 private Pic(int resource, String description){ ... this.desc = . desc etc};

 public boolean isCorrect(String input){
 return input.equals(description);
}
```

Keep a reference to the instance your are using in your imageview, invoke isCorrect() on it with user input and react with feedback accordingly.

Comment: I tried your suggestion in a little example. It works pretty well. I guess I am going to achieve my intention by using enum. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want is [setTag(Object tag)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29)